How to synchronize NPCs across LAN?
As of now, players are synced using:
 if is_network_master():
     do_normal_functions(real_value)
     fake_value = real_value 
else:
    real_value = fake_value 
    do_normal_functions(fake_value)

Every frame I do my normal functions with health... speed, direction or whatever if I'm the network master and I tell myself, "hey take that fake value and give it a real value", if I'm not the network master, I take those fake values and use them for functions.
But how do I synchronize NPCs without creating an entire server structure and hierarchy of lists and such? I just want something simple.

That sounds wrong. How is a client getting the correct value when you use a fake one? What does fake even mean as a position? The usual way is to use sync and RPC (see https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/tutorials/networking/high_level_multiplayer.html) The server would just sync the npc to all clients

If you want the simplest solution then I'd recommend upgrading to Godot 4 and using its built-in MultiplayerSpawner and MultiplayerSynchronizer nodes.

MultiplayerSpawner handles creation/removal of nodes/scenes and syncing these across peers
MultiplayerSynchronizer takes care of synchronizing properties (position, rotation, etc...) of nodes and gives you a great deal of control on what properties you want synchronization to occur (on change, every n seconds, on spawn only and more)

There is detailed documentation and step-by-step tutorials available for this new multiplayer framework. If you can upgrade to take advantage of this, it is by far the most straightforward approach to your problems

The code you shared above likely belongs in a remotesync function, so you must separate the logic between server (network master) and clients (network puppets).
However, there are other keywords to define RPC scope and call permissions among network peers. If you want to allow the network master to change the player's position on all peers, you can use the puppetsync keyword. In your case, the function may look like this:
puppetsync func update_position(value):
    do_normal_functions(value)

No need to distinguish between real_value and fake_value:

A puppet function can only be called by the network master on the network puppets, not vice versa. Therefore, value will always be the "real", authoritative information from the server.
With sync, the function will be called on all peers. Clients will receive the update and so will the player hosting a local game or the dedicated server managing the backend logic.

